# Parallelizing a for Loop which accesses files

Tags: loops, gnu-parallel

Here is the complete code. In BER_SB, values of K,SB passed to rand-src command and value of *sigama* passed to transmit command are being calculated in main. Vlues written to BER array by BER_SB are being further used in main.

```
 BER_SB()
    {
    s=$1        
    mkdir "$1"
    cp ex-ldpc36-5000a.pchk ex-ldpc36-5000a.gen "$1"
    cd "$1"

    rand-src ex-ldpc36-5000a.src $s "$K"x"$SB"
    encode   ex-ldpc36-5000a.pchk ex-ldpc36-5000a.gen ex-ldpc36-5000a.src ex-ldpc36-5000a.enc
    transmit ex-ldpc36-5000a.enc ex-ldpc36-5000a.rec 1 awgn $sigma

    decode   ex-ldpc36-5000a.pchk ex-ldpc36-5000a.rec ex-ldpc36-5000a.dec awgn $sigma prprp 250

    BER="$(verify ex-ldpc36-5000a.pchk ex-ldpc36-5000a.dec ex-ldpc36-5000a.gen ex-ldpc36-5000a.src)"

    echo $BER 

  }
 export BER
 export -f BER_SB


 K=5000 # No of Message Bits
 N=10000 # No of encoded bits

 R=$(echo "scale=3; $K/$N" | bc) # Code Rate



 # Creation of Parity Check and Generator files
  make-ldpc ex-ldpc36-5000a.pchk $K $N 2 evenboth 3 no4cycle
  make-gen  ex-ldpc36-5000a.pchk ex-ldpc36-5000a.gen dense

 # Creation of file to write BER values
 echo>/media/BER/BER_LDPC36_5000_E.txt -n 

 S=1; # Variable to control no of blocks of source messages

 for Eb_No in 0.5 1.0

  do
    B=$(echo "10^($S+1)" | bc) 
    # No of Blocks are increased for higher Eb/No values
    S=$(($S+1))

    # As we have four cores in our PC so we will divide number of source blocks into four subblocks to process these in parallel        
    SB=$(echo "$B/4" | bc) 

    # Calculation of Noise Variance from Eb/No values
    tmp=$(echo "scale=3; e(($Eb_No/10)*l(10))" | bc -l)
        sigma=$(echo "scale=3; sqrt(1/(2*$R*$tmp))" | bc)

    # Calling of functions to process the each subbloc

    parallel BER_SB ::: 1 2 3 4

    BER_T= Here I want to process values of BER variables returned by BER_SB function

done
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. E.g. where do you use $i for anything? I get the feeling you have a bunch of .src files that you want converted to .pchk, .gen, .enc, .rec, and you want that run in parallel. If so, please show us 3 examples of the names of these.

Comment: For what purpose $i is used as I just want same action four times.  rand-src is the command which stores random numbers (1000 blocks each of width 5000) in file ex-ldpc36-500a.src. For each iteration I am changing the seed (not show here) so the contents of all files are changed for each iteration. I am further processing the last file ex-ldpc36-500a.rec to get some results. In each command one files is output and others are input files. I can create four files for each type of file shown and want to process them in parallel on four cores of PC. Right now all of these are single files.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you want done. From what you write it seems you want the same 3 lines run 4 times in parallel. That is easily done:

```
runone() {
  mkdir "$1"
  cd "$1"
  rand-src ex-ldpc36-5000a.src 0 5000 1000
  encode ex-ldpc36-5000a.pchk ex-ldpc36-5000a.gen ex-ldpc36-5000a.src ex-ldpc36-5000a.enc
  transmit ex-ldpc36-5000a.enc ex-ldpc36-5000a.rec 1 awgn .80
}
export -f runone

parallel runone ::: 1 2 3 4
```

But that does not use the '1 2 3 4' for anything. If you want the '1 2 3 4' used for anything you will need to describe better what you really want.

Edit:

It is unclear whether you have:

- Read the examples: LESS=+/EXAMPLE: man parallel
- Walked through the tutorial: man parallel_tutorial
- Watched the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

and whether I can assume that the material covered in those are known to you.

In your code you use BER[1]..BER[4], but they are not initialized. You also use BER[x] in the function. Maybe you forgot that a sub-shell cannot pass values in an array back to its parent?

If I were you I would move all the computation in the function and call the function with all needed parameters instead of passing them as environment variables. Something like:

```
parallel BER_SB ::: 1 2 3 4 ::: 0.5 1.0 ::: $S > computed.out
post process computed.out >>/media/BER/BER_LDPC36_5000_E.txt
```

To keep the arguments in computed.out you can use --tag. That may make it easier to postprocess.

Comment: In serial processing these files are overwritten and so the new data is available to each command. But I think when this code will run in parallel each command will need to access its own files to read and write the data. How this will be handled by parallel?  Means each parallel session will have to access its own files? and how different files will be passed to each parallel session.

Comment: Dear Tange, thanks for providing this code. I am using it now. But now the variables defined in main are not accessible by runone. Befor I was using K, N variables in place of 5000 and 1000 (arguments of rand-src command) but now these are not accessible here. Can I not access now the variable defined in  main? Or I've to pass these explicitly as arguments of parallel? If so then how I'll pass these using parallel. Similarly in runone() I was writing to some variables which are used in main, will these also not accessible in main?

Comment: You can probably just `export` the variables. Edit your question to show what you _really_ want.

Comment: I've edited my question and posted the complete code.

Comment: Dear Tange, I've posted my complete code. Kindly see this and advise me how can I exchange variable between BER_SB function and main programme. Also the message printed on command prompt are not in order as value of BER , which is echoed last in BER_SB, is printed before messages of all other commands. What is reason for this.

Comment: Dear Tange, I am waiting for your advice regarding my above queries.

Comment: Now I've changed the BER array to BER variable and also exporting it. How I can access this variable in main because  each parallel iteration will have its own value.

Comment: As mentioned: You cannot pass values back to the parent using a variable. Use stdout (standard output) as I have suggested.